# Can't load SMSC SCH5317 (driver smsc47b397)

Tags: linux, kernel, driver

my problem is that i can't get the chip SMSC SCH5317 detected by lm-sensors, so i can't control or see fan speed, and it seems that it can't be initialized by the kernel driver. When trying to load the driver with modprobe, the output of dmesg | grep -i smsc is:

```
smsc47b397: found SMSC SCH5317 (base address 0x0000, revision 135)
smsc47b397 smsc47b397.0: Region 0x0-0x1 already in use!
smsc47b397: probe of smsc47b397.0 failed with error -16
```

output of sensors-detect:

```
Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): YES
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x8587
```